# Yuan USD options

Tags: options, foreign-exchange, currency, usd-us-dollar, cny-chinese-yuan

Are there any possibilities for a retail investor to buy a USD/Yuan option other than the ones on the
WisdomTree Chinese Yuan Strategy Fund  ETF (NYSE Arca: CYB) and those from Goldman Sachs? The idea is to bet on a large depreciation of the Yuan.

Comment: Are you only interested in options?  What about non-option instruments that still allow you to profit from a decreasing CNY?

Comment: Yes mainly in options. The low volatility with a currency peg is very favorable for options in my opinion. I know there is a CNY future as well. What would you recommend looking at?